# Parse.com - allow only one session per user

Tags: session, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have an App on Parse platform. What I need:

1. The User logs in on first device.
2. The User logs in on second device.
3. System revokes session on the first device.

I tried to remove objects from Session/Installation classes, but it did not help.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieving this is not quite straightforward as there is no way to intercept login events or write cloud code triggers for Parse `Session` class. If you delete a client session record from the `Session` table, it should certainly revoke it and you end up getting authentication errors on that client. To achieve what you want, you need to write your own cloud function that logs a user in instead of using the SDK login function. That way you can first go through the Session table and revoke/delete any session associated with that user before logging in your user on the new device.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe one of possible solutions is to track sessions and logout if needed on device.

Comment: @Prin53, Did you got any solution for it ?

Comment: NSAnant, unfortunately, no.